# What's the best way to get the current user language and region in daemon/root process in mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to read current user language(preferred language) and region from a daemon process in mac.
  I tried the below code. It works fine while running this piece of code in user space process but it's returning "en" and "us" while this piece of code run from root/daemon process.

```
CFLocaleRef loc = CFLocaleCopyCurrent();
CFStringRef countryCode = (CFStringRef)CFLocaleGetValue (loc, kCFLocaleCountryCode);
CFShow(countryCode);

CFArrayRef langs = CFLocaleCopyPreferredLanguages();
CFStringRef langCode = (CFStringRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex (langs, 0);
CFStringRef langName = CFLocaleCopyDisplayNameForPropertyValue (loc, kCFLocaleLanguageCode, langCode);
CFShow(langCode);
```

What's the best way to get the current user language and region in daemon/root process in mac ?

Any help is appriciated....Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

well if you use NSLocale you have + (id)systemLocale
 it is garanteed to have keys set where currentLocale isn't if you are running as root... I hope they are the keys you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this doesn't solve my problem. What i want is the root process to identify the user locale.

Comment: you would have to change the effective uid... you could do it in a helper tool running as a user (reverse of the normal scenario)

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. Will you please add some sample code for the same...